# Android zxing: How to get product name when a UPC_A code is scanned

Tags: android, zxing

I currently implemented zxing in my app with @Sean Owen's IntentIntegrator (Thanks Sean!). I would like to use the UPC code retrieved to find out the actual product name. I know there is no easy way doing it, but can someone point me to the portion of the code in the zxing source that first showed the product name in the official barcode scanner app? (see attached image).

Around search around, google product is the best place to get product name. However, the result html is quite hard to parse -- since zxing has already figured it out and they are open source, I was wondering if there is an easier to get this done. Thanks.

Edit: What I ended up doing is to look for span key word "owb63p" to retrieve the product, I think zxing does something similar -- you can check out ProductResultInfoRetriever.java under package com.google.zxing.client.android.result.supplement.

Answer (score 1):

Use this URL:

```
http://www.google.com/m/products?q={bar code}
```

For example,

```
http://www.google.com/m/products?q=9781934356173
```

This is written up in more detail [here](http://googlemobile.blogspot.com/2009/05/google-product-search-for-android-now.html).

Comment: I was using google product search and was looking for a way to parse the html result (since initially it appears very messy to me). See my edit in the main thread.

Comment: Ah. Misunderstood the question. You can probably use JSoup (see http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) to extract the appropriate element.

Comment: yes, i indeed am using JSoup. However for this particular one, the regular expression worked out a little better.

Comment: An important note - download the product page as a desktop user agent - it sends a different file version to mobile clients with the default HttpURLConnection settings, and it won't match the regex.